# Checkbox doesn't fire event "Checked" or "Unchecked"

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, checkbox, binding

I'm new to the MVVM pattern and I got a problem with checkboxes inside of a listview.
When I put a checkbox as item into a listview the events "checked" and "unchecked" does not fire.
But when I add a checkbox outside of the listview e.g. in a stackpanel, the events fire.

Could anybody explain the problem?

Thank you in advance.

This is my used code:

```xml
<Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MainMenuColor}">
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItems}" Background="Transparent" Foreground="{StaticResource MainMenuColor}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox FontFamily="{StaticResource FontProtokoll}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Path=Text}" Foreground="{StaticResource MainMenuColor}">
          <behav:Interaction.Triggers>
            <behav:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
              <behav:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CheckedOrUncheckedCommand}"/>
            </behav:EventTrigger>
          </behav:Interaction.Triggers>
        </CheckBox>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Border>
```

Comment: not what you ask, but adding a Command to notify what the `IsChecked` property in the view-model already does, seems to me uselessly redundant. Just leverage the `PropertyCghange` event exposed by the view-model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CheckBox` inherits the `DataContext` of your `ListBox.ItemsSource` binding which is `ListBoxItems`. You are probably trying to call a `Command` that is inside your main `ViewModel`. Assuming that, in order to properly bind to the `ViewModel` you would need to do something like this.

```
xmlns:behav="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
<Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MainMenuColor}">
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItems}" Background="Transparent" Foreground="{StaticResource MainMenuColor}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox FontFamily="{StaticResource FontProtokoll}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Path=Text}" Foreground="{StaticResource MainMenuColor}">
          <behav:Interaction.Triggers>
            <behav:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
              <behav:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext.CheckedOrUncheckedCommand}"/>
            </behav:EventTrigger>
          </behav:Interaction.Triggers>
        </CheckBox>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Border>
```

The `CheckBox` is now binding directly to it's parent `ListBox`s `DataContext` and the `CheckedOrUncheckedCommand` within it.

Also, you could use the `IsChecked` property binding as an alternative depending on your use case.

Comment: Why the extra Border element? It just makes your visual tree unnecessarily complex negatively imnpacting rendering performance. The ListBox already inherits the correct DataContext (in case your assumption is correct and the command *is not* a member of the data item). Just use: {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext.MyCommand}`.

Comment: Did you try this? The border will be in a different namescope to the checkbox. Each item will have it's own namescope, so you could name something in the item template and that not cause errors.

Comment: @Andy I tested this and it will work like this, but a more practical approach might be what BionicCode suggested. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @BionicCode. I used the same code as OP just for an example and so OP can better understand the example. I will update the binding tho as it is more practical.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how your `DataContext` actually looks like (i.e. where the `CheckedOrUncheckedCommand` is defined). Because you wrote the command is properly invoked when the binding is set on an element outside the `DataTemplate` makes it appear like you are binding to the wrong `DataContext`.
The `DataContext` of the `DataTemplate` is *always* the templated data item itself. In your case, its the item inside the `ItemsSource`.
You can fix the binding by setting the `Binding.RelativeSource` property too lookup the element tree fro the element that exposes the correct `DataContext`. In your case the element should be the parent `ListBox`:

```xml
<DataTempate>

  <!-- DataContext is the templated data item.
       In this case its the item inside the `ListBoxItems` source collection that is bound to the ItemsSource. -->
  <CheckBox>
    <behav:Interaction.Triggers>
      <behav:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
        <behav:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext.CheckedOrUncheckedCommand}"/>
      </behav:EventTrigger>
    </behav:Interaction.Triggers>
  </CheckBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

However, the interaction trigger for the `CheckedOrUncheckedCommand` is absolutely redundant and should be removed.
For the sake of readability and maintainability it's always the best to keep any code as simple as possible. Redundancy only leads to confusion as one would assume a deeper meaning where the author simply lacks knowledge instead.
When you find yourself using interaction behaviors to glue the view to its view model, you are usually doing something wrong (in a sense that you could do better and eliminate the overhead introduced by the interaction behavior).

`CheckBox` is a `ButtonBase` and therefore an `ICommandSource`. Simply bind the command to the `CheckBox.Command` property:

```xml
<CheckBox Command="{Binding CheckedOrUncheckedCommand}" />
```

And because you already bind the `CheckBox.IsChecked` property to the same data source, you can event drop the command completely (or the `IsChecked` binding).
Only use one or the other, `CheckBox.IsChecked` or `CheckBox.Command`.

Use either the `CheckBox.Command`:

```xml
<CheckBox Command="{Binding CheckedOrUncheckedCommand}" />
```

```cs
private bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

private void ExecuteCheckedOrUncheckedCommand(object commandParameter)
{
  // Optionally set a property using the XOR operator to toggle it 
  // (CheckBox is a ToggleButton)
  this.IsEnabled ^= true;
}
```

Or use the `CheckBox.IsChecked` property:

```xml
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
```

```cs
// TODO::Property must raise the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event
private bool isEnabled;
public bool IsEnabled 
{ 
  get => this.isEnabled; 
  set 
  {
    this.isEnabled = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.IsEnabled));
    OnIsEnabledChanged();
}

private void OnIsEnabledChanged()
{
  ExecuteCheckedOrUncheckedCommand(null);
}

private void ExecuteCheckedOrUncheckedCommand(object commandParameter)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar issue in WinUI3, and it's right that we need to define the DataContext of the control. In my case, I have a checkbox defined in a grouped header for a DataGrid. What I need is when click the checkbox in the Group header, all checkbox items in this group can be selected.

```
                                            <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Checked"
                                                                               SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=_groupCheckBox}">
                                                <Interactions:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=_dataGrid, Path=DataContext.GroupCheckedCommand}"
                                                                                  CommandParameter="{x:Bind PropertyValue}" />
                                            </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
```